# Android auto save data upon scan result

Tags: android

I have an android app that lets me scan barcodes and it saves to csv upon pressing a save button.

Would it be possible for me to auto-save data upon the scan result of a certain column?

So in short save after scan initiated in a certain edit text location.

**EDIT !:

```
packages and imports used.:
package kinjal.com.barcodescanner;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;**

  //btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn_scanecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            scanBar(view);
        }
    });
    btn_savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String binlocation = edt_binlocation.getText().toString().trim();
            final String islenumber = edt_islenumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String shelfnumber = edt_shelf_number.getText().toString().trim();
            final String sku_barcode = edt_skubarcode.getText().toString().trim();
            final String quantity = edt_quantity.getText().toString().trim();

            if (binlocation.length() == 0)
            {
                edt_binlocation.setError("Enter BIN Location");
            } else if (islenumber.length() == 0) {
                edt_islenumber.setError("Enter ISLE Number");
            } else if (shelfnumber.length() == 0) {
                edt_shelf_number.setError("Enter Shelf Number");
            } else if (sku_barcode.length() == 0) {
                edt_skubarcode.setError("Scan the Item");
            } else if (quantity.length() == 0) {
                edt_quantity.setError("Enter Quantity");
            } else {

                try {
                    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Download/ScannedData");
                    boolean var = false;
                    if (!folder.exists())
                        var = folder.mkdir();
                    final String filename = folder.toString() + "/" + "ScannedDataFile.csv";


                    // show waiting screen
                    // CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.app_name);
                    //FileWriter(filename, boolean append);
                    // output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));

                    try {
                        //BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
                        {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                            String line = br.readLine();
                            if (line == null) {
                                fw.append("BIN Number");
                                fw.write(",");

                                fw.append("ISIE Number");
                                fw.write(",");

                                fw.append("Shelf Number");
                                fw.write(",");

                                fw.append("SKU");
                                fw.write(",");

                                fw.append("Quantity");
                                fw.write(",");
                                fw.write("\n");

                            }

                            fw.append(binlocation);
                            fw.append(',');

                            fw.append(islenumber);
                            fw.append(',');

                            fw.append(shelfnumber);
                            fw.append(',');

                            fw.append(sku_barcode);
                            fw.append(',');

                            fw.append(quantity);
                            fw.append(',');

                            fw.append('\n');
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Row Inserted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            fw.flush();

                            edt_skubarcode.setText("");
                            edt_quantity.setText("1");
                            edt_skubarcode.requestFocus();
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you "scan"ing barcodes ?

Comment: I have a pda device that initiates its scanner to scan barcodes.

Comment: You need to be more specific, is it a barcode scanner that POS systems use or ....

Comment: Sorry. It is a Newland Beluga android pda that I use to scan stock in a retail shop. So I have an app built that will scan barcodes into edit text locations. Then I save the data after i scanned some columns onto a csv file and then I save it onto the device directly. After I made all my scans. I will pull the csv file to the computer.

Comment: Currently the save button does the job. I need to make it more efficient so that I wouldnt have to press save each time, So that when I scan the barcode, it saves automatically

Comment: You may need to think of this in terms of events "After scan complete", save. Are you using a particular library for this sort of thing? Please provide the info to that library if any.

Comment: I am using Kinjal.com barcode scanner package. Forgive me , I am not an android developer. I am very new to this. I thought that I will have to see if an event occured in the edit SKU text field and if so. Save automatically? Am I on the right path? I edited my question to include what i use

Comment: Where is the source of the library, did a quick google-fu on this, is it a repackaged version of [zxing scanner](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) ?

Comment: Correct. I can use ZXING as well.

Comment: Have a look at the example [gist](https://gist.github.com/yamanetoshi/4b7e0444ae09c5a18520) After the IntentIntegrator return the result, do the save in there.

Comment: Okay thanks. Will give it a whack

Comment: Couldn't seem to crack it. Looks like this package works differently.

Comment: I think I should add an addTextChangedListener to the desired field and then pass that to save the data. But no idea where to add this